# Smart way to Handle Null,undefined,isNan,false,empty in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, undefined

I am facing some big problem while checking 'Null, undefined, isNan, false or empty' in my JS. Currently I am using:

```
var dataReturn = '';
var token = getCookie('stateToken');
if (token) {
    dataReturn = token;
}
return dataReturn;
```

In above code 'token' has some value that may be a valid string or 'Null, undefined, isNan, false or empty'. I am using an `IF` statement to check 'Null, undefined, isNan, false or empty'. In most of the cases it is working fine.

But in some case in older browsers, the checking may return some true. I have no idea about whats happening. If anyone have any idea about this please let me know.

Comment: Do you know what values specifically are causing problems?

Comment: @Kolink : Most of the case it return 'undefined'.